# Octave 3.8.2 on Windows 8.1 won't plot

Tags: plot, octave

I seem to be going around in circles trying to get an answer to a problem I am having with Octave 3.8.2 on Windows 8.1: the plot function does not work. Under both gui and cli, the plot screen freezes, nothing is plotted, and Octave shuts down when I remove the plot screen. There seem to be some discussion/suggested solutions for this, but nothing works for me. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please try the octave-4.0.0-rc2-installer.exe from ftp://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/octave/ and see if this version works for you. Be sure to read the hints for Windows8. If you have further problems try the Qt and FLTK toolkit and report to the bugtracker or help mailinglist

Comment: Thanks, Andy. After trying the current set up about 15 times, it seems to have 'woken up'. It may have been all the other suggestions I had tried earlier, but it now seems to be working correctly.

Comment: @mteubner, maybe you could post those other solutions as your own answer. I'm having the same issues with 4.0.0

Comment: Please see this answer of this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39554064/6403137

Comment: Please see the answer of this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39554064/6403137

Answer (score 0):

this is the commen problem with the octave and windows combination .
this can be overcomed very easily by starting the plot function with small values like ' plot([1 2 3 4]) '

after this sirst operatition close the octave and then restart the octave the time will be decreased and we can use for any values,