# Cannot use Octave 4.0.0 graphics toolkit functions under Windows 10

Tags: octave, windows-10

I'm using Octave 4.0.0 on a fresh Windows 10 installation and the graphics toolkit related functions (such as `plot()` or `hist()`) are simply not working. `plot()` creates a new window that freezes immediately in the GUI and no windows at all in the CLI (Octave crashes in both cases). I made sure that `graphics_toolkit()` was set to `"gnuplot"` and not `"fltk"`, but I did not see any improvment. Any suggestion?

Comment: It worked here, but it took more than 1 minute to show the plot. It seems to happen only on the first plot. I ran this: `plot(rand(1, 20))`.

Comment: It actually worked, altough it took much longer than one minute. Gotta be more patient on this notebook. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using the MXE build from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/? Do you see the 1 minute delay with qt, fltk both in the GUI and CLI? I suggest writing a bug report here http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/octave/ with these details so we can try to triage the problem

Comment: Worked for me as well on Octave 4.0.1! I've never experienced this with any software i.e. first time plot hangs for a minute and then it starts working. @Rafael Monteiro - You should put that down as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first time you use `plot`, `imagesc`, or something else that uses plotting functions it will cause Octave to hang for a while (potentially minutes). It may be quicker to plot a small dataset with `plot([1 2 3 4])` initially.

After the initial plot, subsequent ones should be quick, even if you reopen Octave or reboot your computer.

This happens consistently using Octave is `4.0.0`-`4.0.2`, and potentially in other versions on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

Your PC needs to be installed gnuplot separately from SourceForge as Octave gets some errors while installing itself in W8/10.

Here is the link attached. https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/?source=directory

You don't need to change any installation files.

This should work

Answer (score 1):

I have 4.2.0 running on Windows 7. The first time plot takes about a couple of minutes and its faster from then on. The toolkit is "qt".